# why this conversion doesn't work?

Tags: c++, std, stringstream

Below is my func. I call it with

```
if(try_strtol(v, rhs))
```

and RHS = "15\t// comment"

```
bool try_strtol(int64_t &v, const string& s)
{
    try
    {
        std::stringstream ss(s);
        if ((ss >> v).fail() || !(ss >> std::ws).eof())
            throw std::bad_cast();
        return true;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It returns false, i except true with v=15. How do i fix this?

Comment: Why do you expect it to return true? What are you expecting `!(ss >> std::ws).eof()` to evaluate to? or `(s >> v).fail()` for that matter?

Comment: Step 1: Stop trying to be clever. Break up the expression so it is readable, you are not doing anybody any fovours. Especially yourself. Once you have it working with a set of unit tests then try your little optimization trick to see if it still works.

Comment: Actually, I wrote that Martin. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243428/convert-string-to-int-with-bool-fail-in-c/1243435#1243435

Comment: That is the std::stringstream version of boost::lexical_cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to return a boolean, just do this:

```
bool try_strtol(int64_t &v, const string& s)
{
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    return (ss >> v).fail() || !(ss >> std::ws).eof();
}
```

And it's failing because it's a bad cast. Were you hoping the comment would be ignored?

Comment: Yes :D. My stream knowledge is poor and i am in the middle of homework that is due in 2hrs (i have 4 hrs to do it, i was absent). I rather ask how to properly convert an int then write a poor version myself.

Comment: oops, i didnt explain yesterday post. I started it before i went to bed. I woke up 1hr ago.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you expect `(ss >> std::ws).eof()` to be true? rhs contains non-whitespace characters after 15, so the if condition will be true and the exception will be thrown, which is why it returns false.

Answer (score 3):

After std::ws skips the tab, you aren't at eof yet.

Comment: i completely missed that. I didnt understand streams enough and was rushing

Answer (score 0):

If you where expecting that stream IO would handle C++ comment as white space, that isn't the case.