# How do I tell if the c function atoi failed or if it was a string of zeros?

Tags: c++, atoi

When using the function `atoi` (or `strtol` or similar functions for that matter), how can you tell if the integer conversion failed or if the C-string that was being converted was a `0`?

For what I'm doing, `0` is an acceptable value and the C-string being converted may contain any number of `0`s. It may also have leading whitespace.

Comment: Why do you think strtol() is deprecated?  It is a perfectly good, sound function from the C standard.  If you care about success/failure, then you clearly should not use atoi(); there is no way for it to tell you whether it succeeded and returned 0 or failed and returned 0.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that since atoi is deprecated, if it won't work I'd be willing to use strtol if that's a good solution.

Comment: atoi is not deprecated it was never in the standard to begin with.  It was an example from K&R that was seen as a useful extension.

Comment: Very well. I don't know the history or details of atoi and have removed any references to deprecation.

Comment: @stonemetal: Not true. `atoi` and the entire `ato...` company are standard functions. They are present in C99 as well.

Comment: @stonemetal I think you meant `itoa()`, which is MSVC++ only, last I heard.

Comment: @muntoo you are right,  though it must have been there at some point it has a man 3 entry http://linux.die.net/man/3/itoa

Comment: The accepted answer is outdated; see [emlai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28518981/4594973) instead.

Comment: @ray: Thanks for poking me. Been a long time since I've touched this question.

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use atoi()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### For C++11 and later:

The go-to function for string-to-integer conversion is now [**`stoi`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), which takes a `string` and returns an `int`, or throws an exception on error.

No need for the verbose `istringstream` hack mentioned in the accepted answer anymore.

(There's also `stol`/`stoll`/`stof`/`stod`/`stold` for `long`/`long long`/`float`/`double`/`long double` conversions, respectively.)

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer now. Also, note that the exception raised by `std::stoi` is `std::invalid_argument`.

Comment: @ray It may also throw `std::out_of_range`.

Answer (score 51):

The proper function (as long as you are insisting on using C-style functions) is `strtol` and the conversion code might look as follows

```
const char *number = "10"; /* for example */

char *end;
long value = strtol(number, &end, 10); 
if (end == number || *end != '\0' || errno == ERANGE)
  /* ERROR, abort */;

/* Success */
/* Add whatever range checks you want to have on the value of `value` */
```

Some remarks:

`strtol` allows (meaning: quietly skips) whitespace in front of the actual number. If you what to treat such leading whitespace as an error, you have to check for it yourself.

The check for `*end != '\0'` makes sure that there's nothing after the digits. If you want to permit other characters after the actual number (whitespace?), this check has to be modified accordingly.

P.S. I added the `end == number` check later to catch empty input sequences. "All whitespace" and "no number at all" inputs would have been caught by `*end != '\0'` check alone. It might make sense to catch empty input in advance though. In that case `end == number` check will/might become unnecessary.

Comment: It should be `end == number` (no dereference).

Comment: Oops... Sorry. Fixed. Thank you.

Comment: This is a good solution if confined to using C and not C++. I had only been exposed to `atoi` so I didn't know what options were available. Your use of `strol` is obviously a better C solution, but I am able to use C++ (only std libs though) so a template conversion function that simulates `lexical_cast` from the Boost library works best for my use. Thanks though! I'm sure this will come in handy sometime! :)

Comment: Would not the `(end == number)` check be sufficient? The C99 standard says (7.20.1.4-7 for the TR1,2 version of the standard) "If the subject sequence is empty or does not have the expected form, no conversion is performed; the value of nptr is stored in the object pointed to by endptr, provided that endptr is not a null pointer.".

Comment: @mlvljr: Good question. But what about overflow, for one example? Overflow situation does not fall under neither "empty sequence" nor "does not have the expected form" category.

Comment: @AndreyT Ah, really! I just didn't look what the standard exactly means by "the expected form".

Comment: `!= '\0'` is redundant. What is `errno == ERANGE` meant to do?

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX: It is not redundant, as I explained in the answer. It is there to catch inputs like `123abc`. Such inputs are considered "correct" by `strtol` (it stops at `a` and produces `123`). The `!= '\0'` is there to catch such situations.

Comment: I didnt say `*end != '\0'`was redundant. `!=` is an operator that evaluates to 0 if both sides of it are the same. If *end is 0, then `*end != '\0'` evaluates to 0. If *end is nonzero, `*end != '\0'` evaluates to 1 (a non-zero it). Thus, all you need to write is `*end`.

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX: What you are saying is formally correct. But I vocally object to using just `*end` on purely stylistic principles. In my book only values with explicit boolean semantics are allowed to be used in logical expressions without explicit comparison operator. All other values should be used with an explicit comparison operator, regardless of whether it is "redundant" or not. In this particular case I'd regard using `*end` in a logical expression as a bad coding style and a bad programming practice. I personally insist on using `*end != '\0'`.

Comment: Guys, the *title* has C in it. That takes precedence over the tags.

Comment: I am confused, how does this tell the difference between "0" and "sdfdre". Based on the documentation `ERANGE` only happens when you are trying to convert a number out of range, which is not the same thing as trying convert a non number, all that does is return 0.

Answer (score 23):

Since this is tagged [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b):

```
template< typename T >
inline T convert(const std::string& str)
{
    std::istringstream iss(str);
    T obj;

    iss >> std::ws >> obj >> std::ws;

    if(!iss.eof())
        throw "dammit!";

    return obj; 
}
```

Comment: I can use C++ so perhaps this is a better solution than using strtol, but I don't understand this code.

Comment: @Jared: Is it easier to understand if you remove that `template< typename T>` and replace all `T` by `int`? The function initializes an input stream with the string to be read, creates an object, and tries to read from the stream into the object. If the reading fails or anything but whitespace is before/after what's to be read, the function should emit an error (which I've indicated by throwing an exception). If all went well, the object is returned. If you'd be a bit more specific on what's unclear, I could expand on that.

Comment: Now that I've taken some time to understand templates, this makes sense and is a perfect solution! Thanks! I found a more detailed post that has several different options too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243428/convert-string-to-int-with-bool-fail-in-c

Comment: Yes, GMan's version there is a bit more sophisticated. `:)`

Comment: This answer is outdated; see [emlai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28518981/4594973) instead.

Comment: @ray: I have upvoted that one. I can't change acceptance, though.

Answer (score 6):

From the man page for strtol():

> If endptr is not NULL, strtol() stores the address of the first invalid
>        character in *endptr.  If there were no digits at all, however, strtol()
>        stores the original value of nptr in *endptr.  (Thus, if *nptr is not
>        `'\0'` but **endptr is `'\0'` on return, the entire string was valid.)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to `strtol` is `sscanf`, although it's a little heavy-weight:

```
const char *numStr = "12345";  // input string
int value;
if(sscanf(numStr, "%d", &value) == 1)
    ;  // parsing succeeded, use value
else
    ;  // error
```

However, this allows leading whitespace in your string (which may or may not be desirable), and it allows anything to trail the number, so "123abc" would be accepted and return 123.  If you want to have tighter control, go with `strtol()`, as [AndreyT demonstrates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640720/how-do-i-tell-if-the-c-function-atoi-failed-or-if-it-was-a-string-of-zeros/1640804#1640804).

Comment: `sscanf` is better that `atoi` since it provides at least some feedback. However, it is still limited. `sscanf`, unfortunately, can't survive overflow. In case of overflow, `sscanf` produces undefined behavior. This is why `strto...` family is basically the only reliable way to perform the conversion in C standard library.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've done and C/C++, but it would appear to me that the (overly) simple solution would be to check just the string for "0".

```
int value = atoi(string_number.c_str());

if ( !value && string_number != "0" ) {
  // error
} else {
  // great success!
}
```

Comment: What about `00`, `+0`, `-0`, `<whitespace>0`. Are these errors too? I understand that they could be from the user's point of view. But keep in mind that these are not errors from traditional standard library point of view. For example, these are fine by `atoi`, `strtol`, `scanf`...

Comment: string_number may contain any number of zeros, so this is not an ideal solution, though I considered it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: A year latter and a down vote? I wonder why.  Something constructive, hopefully.