# C++ - error while using atoi

Tags: c++, atoi

I am trying to use the `atoi` function in order to obtain conversion from `string` to `int`. The thing is that I have a string array which contains both integers and string values.

From what I've read, in order to get the error code from it, the function must return 0 :

```
string s = "ssss";
int i = atoi(s.c_str())
if (i == 0)
    cout<<"error"<<endl;
end;
```

How should I proceed if my string value is `0` ?

Another issue is with this string : `string s = "001_01_01_041_00.png"`. The `atoi` function returns the value `1`. Shouldn't it return `0`. Why does it return `1`?

Comment: `atoi` converts `string` to `int`. Not `int` to `string` as you said.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I tell if the c function atoi failed or if it was a string of zeros?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640720/how-do-i-tell-if-the-c-function-atoi-failed-or-if-it-was-a-string-of-zeros)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That is why `atoi` is unsafe to use. It doesn't detect and inform the program if the input is invalid.

C++11 has introduced `std:stoi` which is safe, as it throws *exception* if input is invalid in some way. There are also two other variants : `std::stol` and `std:stoll`. See the online documentation for detail:

- [`std::stoi`, `std::stol`, `std::stoll`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

Your code would become this:

```
try {
     string s = "ssss";
     int  i = std::stoi(s); //don't call c_str() 
     //if (i == 0) no need to check!
     std::cout << i << endl;
}
catch(std::exception const & e)
{
     cout<<"error : " << e.what() <<endl;
}
```

Note that the runtime type of `e`  could be either `std::invalid_argument` or `std::out_of_range` depending on the cause of the throw. You could just write two `catch` blocks if you want them to handle differently.

Answer (score 2):

There are already good answers recommending the C++ APIs of std::stoi and boost::lexical_cast.

atoi() is a C API, and broken even in C because you can't tell failure apart from a successful parse of zero. If you're writing C, use strtol() and friends instead if you care about errors, because it reports them out-of-band in ERRNO.

Answer (score 1):

Because the number in `001_` is 1, why should it return 0? If you want to only process one character, just use `isdigit(s[0])` and `s[0]-'0'`. If you want better error checking to see how much of the string contains digit, use `strtol`.

Answer (score 0):

atoi is kind of old ... there's a better replacement in boost lib " lexical cast ".

```
char * str = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(int_value);
```

or

```
int int_value = boost::lexical_cast<int>(string_value);
```