# How can I reach cout << "Sorted:"; when there are no input numbers in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a code to sort a vector of integers. My code is completed, and it works. But it just can't output "Sorted:" when input no number. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

/* sort function */
void sort(vector<int>& v)
{
    for (int inc1 = 0; inc1 < v.size() - 1; ++inc1)
    {
        int minimum = inc1;

        for (int inc2 = inc1; inc2 < v.size(); ++inc2)
        {
            if (v[inc2] < v[minimum])
            {
                minimum = inc2;
            }
        }

        if (minimum != inc1)
        {
            int temporary = v[minimum];
            v[minimum] = v[inc1];
            v[inc1] = temporary;
        }

        if (v.empty())
        {
          return;
        }
    }
}

/* display function */
void display(vector<int> v)
{
    for (int inc1 = 0; inc1 < v.size(); ++inc1)
    {
        cout << v[inc1];
        if (inc1 != v.size() - 1)
        {
            cout << ", ";
        }
    }

    cout << endl;
}

/* main function */

int main()
{
    /* getting inputs */
    cout << "Enter integers (one on each line, entering an empty line quits):" << endl;
    vector<int> v;
    string myString;

    while (getline(cin, myString))
    {
        /* if encounters a empty line, prints the output */
        if (myString.length() == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        /* if not add values to the vector */
        else
        {
            v.push_back(atoi(myString.c_str()));
        }
    }

    cout << "Sorted: ";

    /* function call to sort */
    sort(v);
    /* function call to display */
    display(v);
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: One suggestion use `stoi` instead `atoi`.

Comment: @user1336087: What is the difference?

Comment: Here you go:[Difference between `stoi` vs `atoi`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583945/what-is-the-difference-between-stdatoi-and-stdstoi)

Comment: Please do not change your question _after_ your original question has been answered. It makes existing answers useless. If you have another question post another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have undefined behavior in your code. In your `sort` function you iterate from 0 to `size() - 1` and since the value returned by `size()` is unsigned the value becomes `0xffffffff` on 32 bit systems and `0xffffffffffffffff` on 64 bit systems when the vector is empty.

To get around this check the vector to see if it is empty.

```
void sort(vector<int>& v)
{
    if (v.empty())
    {
        return;
    }

    // ... other code here ...
}
```

Comment: how can I remove the space after "Sorted:" if no input number?

Comment: Use an `if` statement.