# How do you implement your own string to integer conversion

Tags: c++, string, function

So I want to take a string in such as 8302 and convert this into an integer by creating my own function and not using the stoi/atoi functions.

I tried so far by doing:

```
int stringToInt(string input)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(input[i] >= '0' && input[i] <= '9')
    {
        input[i] = input[i] * 10 + ......
        i++;
    }
return i;
}
```

I know i need to keep multiplying by 10 everytime i find an integer so i can increase it e.g 123 = 1*10*10+2*10+3. but i dont know how to code this. could anyone suggest a method?

Comment: Why are you multiplying each ASCII character value in the string by 10?

Comment: You should not be using the same variable for the string index and the accumulator.  Use a separate variable for the accumulator.

Comment: And you're returning the index not the converted number. Also, you don't check for the end of the string.

Comment: And what do you mean by `........` ?

Comment: @FirstStep it's a c++17 feature called the awesomelipsis. An extension of variadic templates, it auto-completes your entire program for you. Simply paste into stack overflow.

Comment: @FirstStep see? 6 answers already :)

Comment: @RichardHodges Cool. What is next? C++20 will take my idea and write the whole code for me. Nice ..... EDIT: I need to move these "....." that I wrote for future clarity!

Comment: This can't be for efficiency. If you're willing to drag in the `<string>` implementation, why object to the [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) function? You can also catch any issues as a [`std::logic_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/logic_error).

Comment: Why not use `stringstream`?

Answer (score 2):

It might be easiest to do it in a recursive manner. Use the following idea:

```
8302 = 830 * 10 + 2
```

That is:

1. If there is only one `char` in the string - return it; otherwise continue
2. Separate the last `char` in the string
3. Convert the string (without the last char) to integer - using recursion
4. Multiply by 10 and add the last `char`

There are a lot of details here:

- how to convert 1 `char` to an integer? - subtract `'0'` from it
- how to separate a `char` from the rest of the string? - use [`substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr)
- when you have a working recursive solution, you might want to convert it to an iterative solution - this will make it faster, but maybe less readable
- what to do with invalid strings like `"aaa"` or `"123haha"` - my algorithm doesn't handle that

Comment: Other points the OP should consider:  a.  Handling negative numbers.  b.  What to do if step 4 would overflow his accumulator (and there are some interesting questions about how to detect that without triggering overflow).  c. Combining the last two: handling entry of the most negative number without triggering overflow.

Comment: I think these considerations are mostly for other people who may read this in future; OP mentioned "stoi/atoi" so he doesn't seem to care about such things, just like [`atoi` doesn't care](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20583945/509868)

Answer (score 1):

Before you could define a *char2int* conversion:

```
inline int ctoi(char c) {
  switch (c) {
    case '0':
      return 0;
    case '1':
      return 1;
    case '2':
      return 2;
    case '3':
      return 3;
    case '4':
      return 4;
    case '5':
      return 5;
    case '6':
      return 6;
    case '7':
      return 7;
    case '8':
      return 8;
    case '9':
      return 9;
    default:
      throw std::runtime_error("Invalid char conversion");
  }
}
```

And use it:

```
int my_stoi_dec(const std::string& str) {
  int rtn = 0;
  int exp = 1;
  for (auto cp = str.crbegin(); cp != str.crend(); ++cp) {
    char c = *cp;
    if (isdigit(c)) {
      rtn +=  ctoi(c) * exp;
      exp *= 10;
    } else if (c == '+') {
      return rtn;
    } else if (c == '-') {
      return rtn * -1;
    } else {
      throw std::runtime_error("Integer error conversion");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should not be using magic numbers.  This makes the code non-portable.

Comment: @NathanOliver better?

Comment: Yes.  This is the most complete answer yet.  It does not handle under/overflow but I am not going to down vote for that.

Answer (score -1):

This one is very close to your attempt:

```
int toInt(const std::string& input)
{
  int i = 0;
  for (const auto c : input)
  {
    if (c < '0' || c > '9')
      break;
    i = i*10 + c-'0';
  }
  return i;
}
```

The only assumption is that the characters `'0'` to `'9'` lie directly next to each other in the character set. The `if` statement makes sure that we stop at non-digit characters. The digit-characters are converted to their integer value using `c-'0'`.

Please keep in mind that this only parses the first digits of a string. Strings that start with a sign `+` or `-` are not considered.

Comment: This is about as clean as it can get. You should add explanations on your answer, because it seems most suitable for using as-is.

Answer (score -1):

A good way is to find your first digit and go from there make a multiplayer variable and multiply it by ten every digit. for every char you add you have to subtract '0' from it as '0' is not equal to int 0.

example:

```
 string s = "12346";
 int multiplayer = 1;
 int i = 0;

 int result = 0;

 while (s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9')
 ++i;

--i;
for(i ; i >= 0 ; --i){
   result += (s[i] - '0') * multiplayer;
   multiplayer *= 10;
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

It is much better that you start your conversion from right to left.

So you will iterate your string starting from its end, and ending on its beginning. On each iteration, we will take the character, convert it to int and multiply it with its `multiplier` (its position in the result integer) and then add it to the final result.

This should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int stringToInt(std::string input)
{
    int result = 0;
    int multiplier = 1;

    for (int i = input.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) // start from right
    {
        if (input[i] - '0' < 0 || input[i] - '0' > 9) // if any character is not an integer, return maximum negative
        {
            result = INT16_MIN;
            break;
        }

        result += (input[i] - '0') * multiplier; // convert to int, get its position and then add it to result.
        multiplier *= 10; // get next position
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::string MyEx = "123456";
    int MyInt = stringToInt(MyEx);

    std::cout << MyInt;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: from OP code and checking, you can not ensure that all the string items are digits

Comment: @HumamHelfawi OP did not state that. Based on his example input, it is not clear that one of the chars might not be an integer. I added it anyway and thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score -3):

```
void enforce( bool b ) {
    if ( !b ) {
        throw std::range_error("Not a valid string to convert to integer");
    }
}

int stringToInt(std::string) {
    for ( std::size_t i( 0 ); i != ( last - first ); ++i ) {
        enforce( ( '0' <= first[ i ] ) && ( first[ i ] <= '9' ) );
        result += pow(10,i) * ( first[ i ] - '0' );
    }
}
```

[Source](https://medium.com/@julienjorge/benchmarking-atoui-a-follow-up-to-writing-fast-code-90e722590f4d#.g27x60fmr)

Comment: `10^i` does not do what you think it does.