# Sort command line args in C++

Tags: c++

I wanna sort an array of command line arguments. All arguments are integer.
Here is my code, but it does not work.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int i=0; i<argc-1; ++i) {
        int pos = i;
        for (int j=i+1; j<argc; ++j) {
            if (argv[j] - '0' < argv[pos] - '0') {
                pos = j;
            }
        }
        char *tempt = argv[i];
        argv[i] = argv[pos];
        argv[pos] = tempt;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<argc; ++i) {
        cout << argv[i] <<endl;
    }
}
```

After compiling, when I called `./a.out 4 3 2 1`,  it still printed `4 3 2 1` to the screen instead of `1 2 3 4`.
What's wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `argv[j] - '0'` doesn't do what you think it's doing.

Comment: Yeah, perhaps you meant `argv[j][0] - '0' < argv[pos][0] - '0'` for a start, and a full `strcmp` for multi-character arguments.

Comment: thx so much! Solved!

Comment: Please contribute back to the community by posting your solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `std::sort` from `<algorithm>` with a custom comparator

```
std::sort(argv, argv + argc, [](char * const & a, char * const & b) {
    return atoi(a) < atoi(b);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In modern c++ you can use `auto` types for lambdas. For string to int convertion I would prefer `stoi` function over `atoi` (you can look for differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20583945/3240681)). Also worth noting that first argument (`argv[0]`) is a program name, e.g. `./a.out`, so you need to skip it from sorting. Final result could be looks like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    std::sort(argv + 1, argv + argc, [](auto l, auto r){ return std::stoi(l) < std::stoi(r); } );
    std::copy(argv + 1, argv + argc, std::ostream_iterator<const char*>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

If all of command line arguments a unsigned number with fixed digits count you could also sort them like string, i.e. without explicit converting to numbers via `std::stoi`. In this case `std::vector<std::string>` could be used:

```
std::vector<std::string> v(argv + 1, argv + argc);
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
```

There is no need to use lambda or another custom comparator for `std::sort`.

Comment: >If all of command line arguments a unsigned number 
Only if they have the same length

Comment: @RiaD true. My bad. Updated.