# How to get int from string (string using like a array of char)

Tags: c++

this little program describes my problem which I have in bigger project:

```
int main()
{
    string str1="11111111";
    string str2="22222222";

    char a=str1[2];
    char *a1=&a;
    int var1= atoi(a1);

    char b=str2[2];
    char *b1=&b;
    int var2= atoi(b1);

    cout<<var1<<endl;
    cout<<var2;


    return 0;
}
```

Why I'm getting

```
1
21
```

istead of

```
1
2
```

?

Is there any way to fix this? - thanks for the help I trying to figureout for two hours

Comment: Strings need to end with the special '\0' character, I believe.

Comment: Undefined behaviour. And never use atoi().

Comment: If all the characters in the string are numbers, [you can just subtract `'0'` (character literal, not integer literal)](http://ideone.com/BonUO1), assuming a character set where all numbers are listed sequentially.

Comment: Also, end the program with another endl after var2 is printed to avoid runtime problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get both results by mistake (even though your first result happens to match your expectation).

The problem is that both `a1` and `b1` point to a single character, while `atoi` expects a null-terminated string.

You can fix this problem by constructing character arrays instead of copying individual characters:

```
char a1[2] = { str1[2] };   // C++ compiler supplies null terminator, you supply the size
int var1= atoi(a1);
char b1[] = { str2[2], 0 }; // You supply null terminator, C++ compiler computes the size
int var1= atoi(b1);
```

Comment: Thanks so much I used your advice to get numbers in loop: 
  https://pastebin.com/wMqV7vZm

Comment: Sorry previous code wasn't good enough - this work perfectly https://ideone.com/u5YGLc

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::stoi()` and `std::string::substr()` especially if you have `std::string` already:

```
std::string str1="11111111";
std::string str2="22222222";

int var1= std::stoi( str1.substr( 2, 1 ) ); // third symbol, 1 symbol long

int var2= std::stoi( str2.substr( 2, 1 ) );
```

[live example](http://ideone.com/tLdU83)

Answer (score 0):

atoi expects a pointer to a null-terminated string of char. You pass a pointer to a char. What happens is undefined. You better use std::stoi instead of atoi since atoi has some fallacies: [What is the difference between std::atoi() and std::stoi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583945/what-is-the-difference-between-stdatoi-and-stdstoi)

Answer (score 0):

`atoi` wants a pointer to the first element of a zero-terminated sequence of characters.
You're passing it a pointer to a single character, leaving undefined behaviour in your wake.

To get the integer value of one of the digits, take its distance from `'0'`:

```
int var = str1[2] - '0';
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly my teacher doesnt allow us to use this methon :/ I have to use atoi :(

Comment: @AdrianWąt That kind of information belongs in the question.