# An issue with clion ide

Tags: c++, clion

Whenever I try using the function stoi() , I get the error “ Use of undeclared identifier ’stoi’ “. So, is it something I have to include in my code or what?

Comment: Answer: Yes, but that has nothing to do with CLion. BTW: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Did you mean `atoi` ??

Comment: You need to include <string>. @majidhajibaba atoi is the old C function; See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583945/what-is-the-difference-between-stdatoi-and-stdstoi) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

To use the [std::stoi](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) function you need to `#include <string>`.

If you don't include the header declaring the function you use, the compiler has no idea what you are trying to call.

This has *nothing* to do with your IDE btw (CLion or something else). That's just basic C++. Include what you use.