# Is a given string convertable to an integer

Tags: c, string, integer

Is there an effective way in C to check if a given string is convertable to an integer?
An output error should indicate if the string is convertable or not.
For example, "aa" is not convertable, "123" is convertable.

Comment: It is probably best to ask two separate questions for this - the best answers for each language are likely very different (although there will be a lot of overlap in people qualified to answer).

Comment: Does "123aa" is convertible to integer for you ?

Comment: "123aa" is not convertable to an integer.

Comment: Check if strspn(str, "0123456789) == strlen(str)

Comment: It's better to decide on either C _xor_ C++. What if someone posts the perfect C answer, and another one posts the perfect C++ answer? Which one will you accept? -- edit: I will remove the C++ tag for you have C answers by now. -- edit: Because the chaos succeeded, I will add the C++ tag again.

Comment: You could try <regex>, if that suits you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++11 has the `std::stoi`, `std::stol`, and `std::stoll` [functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), which throw an exception if the string cannot be converted.

Comment: It's worth noting that these also throw an exception if you try to convert a string containing 1323723172981729817298798271972198728917918729817928 - since it's bigger than the biggest integer. (And that there are `unsigned` variants of all of the above).

Comment: @MatsPetersson `float`ing variants too

Answer (score 3):

With C, use the [strtol(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) function with an end pointer:

```
 char* end=NULL;
 long l = strtol(cstr, &end, 0);
 if (end >= cstr && *end)
    badnumber = true;
 else
    badnumber = false;
```

With C++11, use the [std::strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stol/) function (it raises an exception on failure).

Comment: Why `if (end && ...)`? Do you mean  `if (end > cstr && ...)`? And you have also check for "overflow", compare this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1640804/1187415 to the duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

You could also loop through the string and appply `isdigit` function to each character

Comment: But you have to handle the optional `-` sign prefix!

Comment: And beware of "long" sequences of digits.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool is_convertible_to_int(const std::string &s) {
  try {
    int t = std::stoi(s);
    return std::to_string(t).length() == s.length();
  }
  catch (std::invalid_argument) {
    return false;
  }
}
```