# Reading a file with two words per line into 2 different vectors

Tags: c++, vector

As the title says I'm trying to read a file into two vectors.

The file would look like this

1 hello

2 how

3 are

4 you

Right now I have this, but it doesn't seem to work

```
int number;
string word;
std::vector<int> first;
std::vector<string> second;

ifstream inFile(File);
if (inFile.is_open()) {

  while (inFile >> number >> word) {
    first.push_back(number);
    second.push_back(word);

  }
}
```

Comment: You can't push a `string` into a vector of `int`. Either make `first` a vector of string, or do a string-to-int conversion.

Answer (score 3):

Change the type of `number` to `int`.

Also the `is_open()` is superfluous (unless you have an `else` statement that handles the case when the file can't be opened) as the while loop will fail anyway if the file cannot be opened

Comment: number is of type int, and I do have an else, but thanks

Comment: @user3396692 `number is of type int,` not according to your code above.

Comment: @user3396692 so what is your problem now?

Comment: well it doesnt crash, but its seems the vectors are empty, I could be messing up earlier trying to read the file

Comment: @user3396692 Either way the issue is no longer with the code above, you should either change your question or start a new one and include the relevant parts of your code.

Answer (score 2):

you could use the `atoi()` function i believe in the  header of the std library.
it will convert an ascii string to and integer. so...

```
#include<string>
string number, word;
std::vector<int> first;
std::vector<string> second;

ifstream inFile(File);
if (inFile.is_open()) {

while (inFile >> number >> word) {
  first.push_back(atoi(number));
  second.push_back(word);

 }
}
```

You may need to check to make sure that `atoi()` did not fail before you push onto the vector but this may work for your situation.

Good Luck

EDIT: based on the comment below stating that `atoi()` may be a bad choice i will amend my answer. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663709/convert-string-to-int-c) link. It's accepted answer recommends using `std::stoi()`
so to amend my answer...

```
#include<string>
string number, word;
std::vector<int> first;
std::vector<string> second;

ifstream inFile(File);
if (inFile.is_open()) {

while (inFile >> number >> word) {
  first.push_back(std::stoi(number));//changed this line
  second.push_back(word);

 }
}
```

Comment: You should generally avoid `atoi` in C++ as it make error handling hard -- see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640720/how-do-i-tell-if-the-c-function-atoi-failed-or-if-it-was-a-string-of-zeros/1640804#1640804

Comment: @Soren I have amended my answer to take this into account. thank you for your input.

Comment: .. for reference: some really good discussion on the virtues of `std::atoi` vs `std::stoi` can be found here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583945/what-is-the-difference-between-stdatoi-and-stdstoi

Comment: I've made the changes, and now its gives me an error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*'

Comment: @user3396692 Did you change number to an `int`? that would probably cause the error. For my answer number will be a `string` not an `int`. my answer will not work in conjunction with the answer from @user657267

Comment: I see that, sorry my mistake on the type. yes the intention is for number to be int

Comment: @user3396692 Were you able to fix the issue? What i meant was that if you are going to go in the direction i proposed that the variable `number` would need to be a `string` and that it would be converted to and `int` by `std::stoi(number)` in the line `first.push_back(std::stoi(number));`