# Parse C++ class and parameters from file/command line and write them to a table/file

Tags: c++, configuration, command-line-arguments

Disclamer: I'm using C++11.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41442100/generic-object-creation-from-command-line) question I was asking how I could create objects from command line. A good solution was proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41450646/4480180). Since then, I developed my system and multiple classes and arguments are created from command line. Just as an example:

```
./myprogram param1 1 param2 "hello" class1 3 8.8 "string_option" class2 1
```

What this execution does is:

1. set the optional variable/parameter `int param1=1`
2. set the optional variable/parameter `std::string param2=hello`
3. create an object of `class1` with the constructor `class1(int first, float second)`
4. create an ojbect of `class2` with the constuctor `class2(int first)`

Creating objects from `class1` and `class2` are mandatory, while setting `param1` and/or `param2` is optional.

So this calling is legal too (missing `param1`):

```
./myprogram param2 "hello" class1 3 8.8 "string_option" class2 1
```

While this is not (missing `class1`):

```
./myprogram param1 1 param2 "hello" class2 1
```

I'm doing this because I need to test several different configurations (i.e. tuning) and find the best one.

Finally, I need to write each configuration to a file/table with the correspondent result, so I can easily compare the results from different configurations.

My question is: is there any already implemented or better solutioin? Like using some configuration file (for exmample a `.yml` file) or for example some cool library (`boost` I'm looking at you :) ).

Comment: This is one of the reason why there are argument parsers that handle named options. So you can write something like `./myprogram --param1=value1 --param2=value2` etc. You might want to look into e.g. [Boost program options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/program_options.html).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for your comment. I thought about program obtions by boost, but I wonder how I could use it with `class1` where it's not a `(key,value)` as you can see from the question.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude And btw how could I write them to file?