# convert pointer string to integer

Tags: c++, string, integer, pointers

I am trying to convert `treePtr->item.getInvest()` which contains a string to an integer. Is this possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243428/convert-string-to-int-with-bool-fail-in-c/1243444#1243444

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#include <sstream>

// ...

string str(*(treePtr->item.getInvest())); // assuming getInvest() returns ptr
istringstream ss(str);
int the_number;
ss >> the_number;
```

Comment: It works, but it is inefficient - there's at least one heap allocation and free there, which may well get stuck in a mutex if your program in multi-threaded. Are you doing this once, or millions of times?

Comment: wilhelmtell: Just because we are writing C++ does not mean that everything has to be a class. Premature optimisation may be the root of all evil, but wilfully choosing to do extra work is perverse.

Answer (score 8):

if you have access to boost:

```
int number= boost::lexical_cast<int>(treePtr->item.getInvest());
```

Answer (score 4):

Better to use `strtol()` than mess around with streams.

```
const char* s = treePtr->item.getInvest();
const char* pos;
long the_number = ::strtol(s,&pos,10);
if(pos!=s)
    // the_number is valid
```

`strtol()` is a better choice because it gives you an indication of whether number returned is valid or not. Furthermore it avoids allocating on the heap, so it will perform better. If you just want a number, and you are happy to accept a zero instead of an error, then just use `atol()` (which is just a thin wrapper around `strtol` that returns zero on error).

Comment: "Better to use strtol" ... why?

Comment: Streams are "the C++ way."  I prefer it to worrying about getting all the details associated with C strings right.

Comment: Shmoopty: fair question. I have added my reasoning to the answer.

Comment: mch: Streams certainly have their place, but a straight replacement for `strtol()` is not one of them. Just as you would not use a `std::string` when a `const char*` would suffice.

Comment: +1 for this answer. streams have their place but are very inefficient. you could do a template specialization for boost::lexical_cast<int> that uses strtol

Comment: but it is sometimes best to get amature developers to use strings and functions that avoid seg faults from incorrect array sizes and access when using char*'s.
I find that char* issues are a large percentage of the bugs in peoples code unless they are good, careful programmers

Comment: @alex tingle streams do have error states, and stringstreams use them when a parse fails.