# Converting a string into an integer parameter

Tags: c++, string, function, integer

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to convert a number to string and vice versa in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290089/how-to-convert-a-number-to-string-and-vice-versa-in-c)
>   [c++ - convert pointer string to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655904/c-convert-pointer-string-to-integer)

Is there a way to convert a string into an integer parameter without any big algorithms?

```
string = "100";

integerFunction(int string);
```

I've tried atoi functions and tried to manually convert each number over with the string[count] - 48 way but it needs to be in a way where the number of digits don't become a problem with this. Any suggestions or algorithms out there that can help? I really appreciate it.

Comment: Why would the number of digits be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
int StringToInt( const std::string & str )
{
  std::stringstream ss(str);
  int res = 0;
  ss >> res;
  return res
}
```

Comment: Why not use the stringstream constructor :P std::stringstream ss(str);

Comment: What advantage does this have over calling `strtol`, exactly?