# How do I check if a C++ string is an int?

Tags: c++, string, types, stringstream

When I use `getline`, I would input a bunch of strings or numbers, but I only want the while loop to output the "word" if it is not a number.
So is there any way to check if "word" is a number or not? I know I could use `atoi()` for
C-strings but how about for strings of the string class?

```
int main () {
  stringstream ss (stringstream::in | stringstream::out);
  string word;
  string str;
  getline(cin,str);
  ss<<str;
  while(ss>>word)
    {
      //if(    )
        cout<<word<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243428/convert-string-to-int-with-bool-fail-in-c/1243435#1243435

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Another version...

Use [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol), wrapping it inside a simple function to hide its complexity :

```
inline bool isInteger(const std::string & s)
{
   if(s.empty() || ((!isdigit(s[0])) && (s[0] != '-') && (s[0] != '+'))) return false;

   char * p;
   strtol(s.c_str(), &p, 10);

   return (*p == 0);
}
```

#### Why `strtol` ?

As far as I love C++, sometimes the C API is the best answer as far as I am concerned:

- using exceptions is overkill for a test that is authorized to fail
- the temporary stream object creation by the lexical cast is overkill and over-inefficient when the C standard library has a little known dedicated function that does the job.

#### How does it work ?

`strtol` seems quite raw at first glance, so an explanation will make the code simpler to read :

`strtol` will parse the string, stopping at the first character that cannot be considered part of an integer. If you provide `p` (as I did above), it sets `p` right at this first non-integer character.

My reasoning is that if `p` is not set to the end of the string (the 0 character), then there is a non-integer character in the string `s`, meaning `s` is not a correct integer.

The first tests are there to eliminate corner cases (leading spaces, empty string, etc.).

This function should be, of course, customized to your needs (are leading spaces an error? etc.).

#### Sources :

See the description of `strtol` at: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol.

See, too, the description of `strtol`'s sister functions (`strtod`, `strtoul`, etc.).

Comment: +1, by far the best answer. lexical_cast is overkill and it borders on bad practice.

Comment: @David Titarenco : `lexical_cast is overkill and it borders on bad practice` : Only when used carelessly, and the same can be said for any other feature. The real use of boost::lexical_cast is for generic code, or quick and dirty code. **Generic code:** When you have an unknown type T, using a switch to use strtol, strtol, etc. is a mistake. Using a boost::lexical_cast is the right thing, providing the boost::lexical_cast specializations for the right types for efficient use. **Quick'n'dirty code:** If that code does not need speed, then using boost::lexical_cast is the easiest way to do it.

Comment: Why are you talking about exceptions and `lexical_cast` being overkill and inefficient, when you didn't measure at all (or, if you did, you didn't show the results)?

Comment: On my system (GCC 9.2.0) I find that the corner-case-check of `!isdigit(s[0])) && (s[0] != '-') && (s[0] != '+')` isn't necessary, `strtol` just does that anyway. The check for an empty string has to be there, though.

Answer (score 74):

The accepted answer will give a false positive if the input is a number plus text, because "stol" will convert the firsts digits and ignore the rest.

I like the following version the most, since it's a nice one-liner that doesn't need to define a function and you can just copy and paste wherever you need it.

```
#include <string>

...

std::string s;

bool has_only_digits = (s.find_first_not_of( "0123456789" ) == std::string::npos);
```

EDIT: if you like this implementation but you do want to use it as a function, then this should do:

```
bool has_only_digits(const string s){
  return s.find_first_not_of( "0123456789" ) == string::npos;
}
```

Comment: "it's a nice one-liner that doesn't need to define a function and you can just copy and paste wherever you need it", but you should define a function. Please don't copy and paste code.

Comment: @FerdinandoRandisi What about negative numbers?

Comment: True, this wouldn't work for negative numbers. But you can check if the first character is a + or a -, and if that's the case just pass the rest of the string.

Comment: Wow, this is a great answer! Never would have thought of it

Comment: @Deqing that's true. If you happen to modify it so that it works for both positive and negative integers I'd be happy to edit my answer.

Comment: For negative numbers to be considered, just add `-` in the param of `find_first_not_of`: s.find_first_not_of("0123456789+-") == std::string::npos
Also, put `+` and `-` in case the string contains +42 (like 42) or -42.

Comment: @CaioV. doing that will result in strings like 23-431+ being accepted as well. It's better to put a check at the start of the function for a + or - and then remove the first character if there is one.

Answer (score 17):

You might try `boost::lexical_cast`. It throws an `bad_lexical_cast` exception if it fails.

In your case:

```
int number;
try
{
  number = boost::lexical_cast<int>(word);
}
catch(boost::bad_lexical_cast& e)
{
  std::cout << word << "isn't a number" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: throwing and catching exceptions in string parsing code just slows everything down to a crawl.

Answer (score 9):

If you're just checking if `word` is a number, that's not too hard:

```
#include <ctype.h>
```

...

```
string word;
bool isNumber = true;
for(string::const_iterator k = word.begin(); k != word.end(); ++k)
    isNumber &&= isdigit(*k);
```

Optimize as desired.

Answer (score 5):

Use the all-powerful C stdio/string functions:

```
int dummy_int;
int scan_value = std::sscanf( some_string.c_str(), "%d", &dummy_int);

if (scan_value == 0)
    // does not start with integer
else
    // starts with integer
```

Comment: If `sscanf` returns the number of matched items, then your example (comments) is wrong. Or do I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, the way I see it you have 3 options.

1: If you simply wish to check whether the number is an integer, and don't care about converting it, but simply wish to keep it as a string and don't care about potential overflows, checking whether it matches a regex for an integer would be ideal here.

2: You can use boost::lexical_cast and then catch a potential boost::bad_lexical_cast exception to see if the conversion failed. This would work well if you can use boost and if failing the conversion is an exceptional condition.

3: Roll your own function similar to lexical_cast that checks the conversion and returns true/false depending on whether it's successful or not. This would work in case 1 & 2 doesn't fit your requirements.

Comment: Pick A. Regex won't tell you if it overflows the range of an integer.

Comment: Original question doesn't mention wanting to check for overflows or even wanting to use a number as an integer.  For all I'd know, they're planning on keeping the number in a string to avoid such limits.

Comment: Alright, I tried changing the reply to include the 3 options I had originally listed, with a reason for each of them.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `boost::lexical_cast`, as suggested, but if you have any prior knowledge about the strings (i.e. that if a string contains an integer literal it won't have any leading space, or that integers are never written with exponents), then rolling your own function should be both more efficient, and not particularly difficult.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution.

```
try
{
  (void) std::stoi(myString); //cast to void to ignore the return value   
  //Success! myString contained an integer
} 
catch (const std::logic_error &e)
{   
  //Failure! myString did not contain an integer
}
```

Comment: Exceptions should not be used for normal operations and flow control. They should only be used for... you guessed it: exceptions. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Warning: It won't work anyway, std::stoi won't throw, it will return 0 in case of failure.

Answer (score 3):

Since C++11 you can make use of [std::all_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) and [::isdigit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

int main([[maybe_unused]] int argc, [[maybe_unused]] char *argv[])
{
    auto isInt = [](std::string_view str) -> bool {
        return std::all_of(str.cbegin(), str.cend(), ::isdigit);
    };

    for(auto &test : {"abc", "123abc", "123.0", "+123", "-123", "123"}) {
        std::cout << "Is '" << test << "' numeric? " 
            << (isInt(test) ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Check out the result with [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/D7MZx9).

Answer (score 2):

```
template <typename T>
const T to(const string& sval)
{
        T val;
        stringstream ss;
        ss << sval;
        ss >> val;
        if(ss.fail())
                throw runtime_error((string)typeid(T).name() + " type wanted: " + sval);
        return val;
}
```

And then you can use it like that:

```
double d = to<double>("4.3");
```

or

```
int i = to<int>("4123");
```

Comment: I'd rather use boost::lexical_cast.

Comment: @SebastianMach So does the original example.

Answer (score 2):

I have modified [paercebal's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2845275/3744681) to meet my needs:

```
typedef std::string String;    

bool isInt(const String& s, int base){
   if(s.empty() || std::isspace(s[0])) return false ;
   char * p ;
   strtol(s.c_str(), &p, base) ;
   return (*p == 0) ;
}


bool isPositiveInt(const String& s, int base){
   if(s.empty() || std::isspace(s[0]) || s[0]=='-') return false ;
   char * p ;
   strtol(s.c_str(), &p, base) ;
   return (*p == 0) ;
}


bool isNegativeInt(const String& s, int base){
   if(s.empty() || std::isspace(s[0]) || s[0]!='-') return false ;
   char * p ;
   strtol(s.c_str(), &p, base) ;
   return (*p == 0) ;
}
```

---

**Note:**

1. You can check for various bases (binary, oct, hex and others)
2. Make **sure** you don't pass `1`, negative value or value `>36` as base.
3. If you pass `0` as the base, it will auto detect the base i.e for a string starting with `0x` will be treated as hex and string starting with `0` will be treated as oct. The characters are case-insensitive.
4. Any white space in string will make it return false.