# How can I know whether my C++ string variable is a number or not

Tags: c++, string, parsing

I have a string of class string

```
string str;
```

how can I check if it is a number or not, str can only have 3 possible types described below like

```
abcd
```

or a number like

```
123.4
```

or a number with a parenthesis attach to the end it for example

```
456)
```

note the parenthesis at the end of "str" is the only possible combination of number and none number

where the bottom two are considered valid numbers, I know I could use lexical_cast if only the first 2 cases occur, but how about considering all 3 possible cases to occur?
I don't need to do anything fancy with str, I just need to know whether it is a valid number as I described

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844817/how-do-i-check-if-a-c-string-is-an-int

Comment: Wow. In my month and a half at SO, I can't say I've ever seen a duplicate posted 3 hours after the original.

Comment: @Maulrus but have you seen an elephant fly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C++ solution for parsing strings manually is string streams. Put your string into a `std::istringstream` and read from that.

What you could do to parse this is to try to read an (`unsigned`) `int` from the string.
If this fails, it is a string not starting with digits.
If it works, peek at the next character. If that's a `.` you have a floating point number, if it's a `)`, you have an integer number. (Otherwise you have a reading error.)

Something along the lines of

```
void read(const std::string& str)
{
  std::istringstream iss(str);
  int i;
  if( !(iss>>i) ) {
    // str contains "abcd"
  } else {
    switch( iss.peek() ) {
      case ')': 
        // i contains '456'
        break;
      case '.' {
        double d;
        if( !(iss>>d) ) throw "dammit!";
        d += i;
        // d contains floating point value
        break;
      default: throw "what?!";
  }
  // ...
}
```

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define "number". There isn't a generic "number" type (for example, your first number is a double while the second is an integer).

That said, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243428/convert-string-to-int-with-bool-fail-in-c/1243435#1243435), `lexical_cast` simply checks that the destination *and only* the destination exists:

```
template <typename R, typename T>
R lexical_cast(const T& pX)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << pX;

    R result;               // take out any whitespace, make sure nothing is left
    if ((ss >> result).fail() || !(ss >> std::ws).eof())
    {
        throw std::bad_cast();
    }

    return result;
}
```

So just make a new function:

```
template <typename R, typename T>
R weak_lexical_cast(const T& pX)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << pX;

    R result;
    if ((ss >> result).fail())
    {
        throw std::bad_cast();
    }

    return result;
}
```

It's basically a `lexical_cast` but doesn't care about any remaining characters (allowing your second number to work.)

Answer (score 0):

maybe a regular expression would do the trick for you.

Comment: Despite the negative vote this isn't such a bad idea. Could you given an example?