# Forcing String to int Function to Consume Entire String

Tags: c++, string, atoi, string-conversion, extraction-operator

Given a string that should represent a number, I'd like to put it into a conversion function which would provide notification if the *whole* string did not convert.

For input: `"12"`:

- `istringstream::operator>>` outputs 12
- `atoi` outputs 12
- `stoi` outputs 12

For input `"1X"` I'd like a failure response but I get:

- `istringstream::operator>>` outputs 1
- `atoi` outputs 1
- `stoi` outputs 1

For input `"X2"`:

- `istringstream::operator>>` outputs 0 and sets an error flag
- `atoi` outputs 0
- `stoi` throws an error

[[Live Example](http://ideone.com/V25Suc)]

Is there a way to provoke the error behavior on input `"1X"`?

Comment: I think you have answers in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844817/how-do-i-check-if-a-c-string-is-an-int and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243428/convert-string-to-int-with-bool-fail-in-c/1243435#1243435

Comment: @deepmax Yup, for the purposes of a minimal example I didn't include it, but in my local test code I'm doing this at the top of the loop: `cout << "\tinput string: " << i << (all_of(i, i + strlen(i), bind(isdigit, placeholders::_1)) ? " is good\n" : " is bad\n");` However, even though I *can* check this way I don't want to. All the other functions must step through each character as well and I would like to have a way to harness what they already know.

Comment: @deepmax You are wrong this is not a duplicate, those answers do **not** address verifying that the whole string has been read.

Comment: I agree that this is not a duplicate. It asks a different question, which is not answered by the linked answers. @deepmax you should un-mark it.

Comment: Anyway, here's the answer: int pos; int n = stoi(mystring, &pos); if (pos != mystring.length()) it's not numeric.

Comment: I've reopened the question, but I believe it's a dup since they are answering the question right to the point.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou That's exactly what I needed, can you put that as an answer?

Comment: @JonathanMee: The comment that KlitosKyriacou provided is in the answers of the links that I've posted (and more detailed). Read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1243531/952747

Comment: You're right, deepmax, although those answers use strtol instead of stoi (which is what I had searched for). In some libraries, stoi is implemented in terms of strtol, so those answers can be adapted.

Comment: @deepmax Neither of your linked answers even contains the text `stoi`. I was able to find [a solution that uses `strtol`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1243531/2642059) which is also viable. However, just because an answer that answers my question is provided on a separate question does *not* make it a duplicate. I searched http://www.stackoverflow.com for a question about converting an *entire* string into a number, and there wasn't one. This question saves the next person from having to re-ask it.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou I went ahead and added [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32997831/2642059) lest the question should be re-closed, as I don't think that there is a well documented answer for this question available. I did use `stoi` as you suggested, and as such if you want to type up an answer I will accept yours as you were onto the right of it first.

Comment: That's ok Jonathan, your own answer is much more detailed and helpful than anything I would have written.

Comment: @deepmax Thank you for un-closing. I believe the information presented in this question and answer will be very helpful to anyone suffering from a problem similar to mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) or later `from_chars` is preferred. See here for more: https://topanswers.xyz/cplusplus?q=724#a839

---

For a given `string str` there are several ways to accomplish this each with advantages and disadvantages. I've written a live example here: https://ideone.com/LO2Qnq and discuss each below:

## [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol)

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1243531/2642059) `strtol`'s out-parameter can be used to get the number of characters read. `strtol` actually returns a `long` not an `int` so a cast is happening on the return.

```
char* size;
const int num = strtol(str.c_str(), &size, 10);

if(distance(str.c_str(), const_cast<const char*>(size)) == str.size()) {
    cout << "strtol: " << num << endl;
} else {
    cout << "strtol: error\n";
}
```

Note that this uses `str.c_str()` to refer to the same string. [`c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) Returns pointer to the underlying array serving as character storage not a temporary if you have C++11:

> `c_str()` and `data()` perform the same function

Also note that the pointer returned by `c_str` will be valid between the `strtol` and `distance` calls unless:

> - Passing a non-`const` reference to the `string` to any standard library function
> - Calling non-`const` member functions on the `string`, excluding `operator[]`, `at()`, `front()`, `back()`, `begin()`, `rbegin()`, `end()` and `rend()`

If you violate either of these cases you'll need to make a temporary copy of `i`'s underlying `const char*` and perform the test on that.

## [`sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf)

`sscanf` can use `%zn` to return the number of characters read which may be more intuitive than doing a pointer comparison. If base is important, `sscanf` may not be a good choice. Unlike `strtol` and `stoi` which support bases 2 - 36, `sscanf` provides specifiers for only octal (`%o`), decimal (`%d`), and hexadecimal (`%x`).

```
size_t size;
int num;

if(sscanf(str.c_str(), "%d%zn", &num, &size) == 1 && size == str.size()) {
    cout << "sscanf: " << num << endl;
} else {
    cout << "sscanf: error\n";
}
```

## [`stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32991193/forcing-string-to-int-function-to-consume-entire-string?noredirect=1#comment53809197_32991193) `stoi`'s output parameter works like `sscanf`'s `%n` returning the number of characters read. In keeping with C++ this takes a `string` and unlike the C implementations above `stoi` throws an [`invalid_argument`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/invalid_argument) if the first non-whitespace character is not considered a digit for the current base, and this unfortunately means that unlike the C implementations this must check for an error in both the `try` and `catch` blocks.

```
try {
    size_t size;
    const auto num = stoi(str, &size);

    if(size == str.size()) {
        cout << "stoi: " << num << endl;
    } else {
        throw invalid_argument("invalid stoi argument");
    }
} catch(const invalid_argument& /*e*/) {
    cout << "stoi: error\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use `std::istringstream` as you mentioned, but check to make sure it parsed to the end of the stream. Assuming you have a constant reference, you could do something like the following

```
T parse(const std::string& input) {
    std::istringstream iss(input);
        T result;
        iss >> result;
        if (iss.eof() || iss.tellg() == int(input.size())) {
            return result;
        } else {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Couldn't parse entire string");
    }
}
```

The benefit of this approach is that you parse anything that overloads `operator>>`. Note: I'm not entirely sure if the condition is enough, but with my testing it seemed to be. For some reason the stream would get a failure marking if it parsed to the end.

Comment: I've given you a +1 because this maybe a very helpful way to do the conversion for someone who needs to work further with an `istringstream` and could incorporate your solution, however in the general case I believe one of the more lightweight conversions in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32997831/2642059) should be used.