# regex with only numbers in a string c++

Tags: c++, regex, string, c++11, numbers

I'm looking for a regex to find numbers in a string; if I have a string like:

`li 12.12 si 43,23 45 31 uf 889 uf31 3.12345`

I want to find only the numbers:

`12.12 45 31 889 3.12345`

I tried with the following pattern:

`((\\+|-)?[[:digit:]]+)(\\.(([[:digit:]]+)?))?`

but the output included `uf31` and `43,23`.

I tried with:

`(?!([a-z]*((\\+|-)?[[:digit:]]+)(\\.(([[:digit:]]+)?))?[a-z]*))?((\\+|-)?[[:digit:]]+)(\\.(([[:digit:]]+)?))?`

but this gave the same result.

What is the solution?

SOLUTION 
leave to posterity the solution:

- If you're looking for a simple and effective solution that does not use the regex, see [Jonathan Mee's post below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33521413/2642059)
- If you're looking for a solution using RegEx, see [the wonderful regex from stribizhev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33521564/2642059)

  `R"((?:^|\s)([+-]?[[:digit:]]+(?:\.[[:digit:]]+)?)(?=$|\s))"`

Comment: Can you define what you want to use for delimiters? I understand that you do *not* want to include anything but whitespace delimited numbers. Is that correct?

Comment: Do you want to support `.5`?

Comment: How about scientific notation? You'll need to be specific about what you want to be able to capture. Your example string contains no + or - and you don't mention them in text, but your regexp attempts do.

Comment: @stribizhev I wouldn't mind offering an upvote if the OP made it clear what he was looking for.

Comment: I would instead replace all unbroken whitespace `\s+` with single space `\s` then I would split on `\s` and test each item in turn

Comment: @JonathanMee Yes, it's correct

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Nope, it's print '5'

Comment: @user2079303 right, but i include plus or minus notation. For scientific notation i don't need

Comment: @user3641602: Sry, I don't understand your answer. print '5'??

Comment: @user2079303 As we suggested use of `strtod` gets scientific notation support for free.

Comment: @Mike P 
Thanks for the edit 
But tag c++ it's important because regex in c++ are different respect to regex in c# or another languages

Comment: @user3641602 The correct way to specify a solution is to accept an answer by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer.

Comment: @JonathanMee thank you mery much jonathan! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, C++ regex module *supports look-aheads*.

Here is my suggestion:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::string buffer = " li 12.12 si 43,23 45 31 uf 889 uf31 3.12345";
    std::regex rx(R"((?:^|\s)([+-]?[[:digit:]]+(?:\.[[:digit:]]+)?)(?=$|\s))"); // Declare the regex with a raw string literal
    std::smatch m;
    std::string str = buffer;
    while (regex_search(str, m, rx)) {
        std::cout << "Number found: " << m[1] << std::endl; // Get Captured Group 1 text
        str = m.suffix().str(); // Proceed to the next match
    }  
    return 0;
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/3nOQEZ)

Due to the raw string literal declaration, there is no need using double backslashes with `\s`.

The lookahead `(?=$|\s)` checks the presence, but does not consume the whitespace and consecutive numbers can be extracted.

Note that if you need to extract decimal values like `.5`, you need

```
R"((?:^|\s)([+-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]+)(?=$|\s))"
```

Comment: I stand corrected, I was using Visual Studio 2013 last I tested look arounds. It appears C++ now fully supports ECMAScript! However I'd still make the case that look arounds are the most expensive regex operation. They should be avoided unless absolutely necessary, which they aren't here.

Comment: In this case, following this logic, the look-ahead is *a must*. You can't match the numbers in `<SPACE>41<SPACE>31<SPACE>` without a look-ahead.

Comment: Is your `"<SPACE>"` a literal whitespace? If not from my understanding the OP wouldn't want those numbers to match. If it is a literal whitespace I don't see why you need look arounds?

Comment: @JonathanMee: Please have a look at [your results](https://regex101.com/r/pU6gB8/1) - your regex does not match the expected `31`.

Comment: Cancel that, [my regex without lookarounds did work fine](https://ideone.com/JSuULo) but I believe that the best solution is the use of `strtod`, which I have changed my answer to use.

Comment: @user3641602: Glad it works for you, please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: @stribizhev just once: why do you write R before regex??

Comment: It is a raw string literal. The notation is `R"()"`. Inside the parentheses, ``\`` symbol means a literal ``\`` symbol, not a C-escaping symbol.

Answer (score 1):

You need this regex:

```
(?<!,)\b([\d\.]+)\b(?!,)
```

Comment: thank! but with your regex i print
`token .
token ,
token .`

Comment: @user3641602 This will match 1.2.3... Do you want to enforce correct numbering on your number?

Comment: This regex also retrieves `43,23` and the 31 from `uf31`. Don't think that's what the OP wanted.

Comment: do you need 43 and 23 separately and don't want 31 from the uf31?
Am I right?

Comment: Then you need to just modification in current regex: `\b([\d\.]+)\b`

Comment: From the question it seems that the OP does *not* want `"43,23"` to be captured, that seems to be one of the reasons that he asked the question in the first place. But he also doesn't seem to want numbers that are not whitespace delimited from letters.

Comment: @MayurKoshti No that's wrong. That will still pick up the 43 and 23 from `"43,23"` which the OP expressedly stated that he did *not* want.

Comment: Sorry Jonathan Mee!
I modified regex :
`(?<!,)\b([\d\.]+)\b(?!,)`

Comment: This has the bugs of your original regex: it captures 1.2.3... but now it's also picked up the need for Boost in the regex by @KarolyHorvath

Comment: I modified my original regex.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath the current, modified answer gives the output that OP wants with the given string. Since OP doesn't specify what kind of numbers they want and what they don't want, I'd say this answer is a simple solution.

Comment: @user2079303 No it does *not* give what the OP wants, he doesn't want to capture the 43 or 23 from `"43,23"` this will capture that.

Comment: @JonathanMee no, it does not. The look-ahead and look-behind checks for comma prevent that. Unless the engine doesn't support those - like you asserted in a comment to another answer - this does not capture `43,23`.

Comment: @user2079303 Correction, I meant to type that this will pull from any symbol other than a comma: `"12#3"` for example will capture 12 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

As is [stated by stribizhev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520934/regex-with-only-numbers-in-a-string-c/33521190?noredirect=1#comment54825028_33521564) this can only be accomplished via look arrounds. Since a single whitespace separating numbers would otherwise be needed to be consumed in the search for the number before and after the whitespace.

[user2079303 poses a viable option to regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33522642/2642059) which could be simplified to the point where it rivaled the simplicity of a regexes:

```
for_each(istream_iterator<string>(istringstream(" li 12.12 si 43,23 45 31 uf 889 uf31 3.12345")),
         istream_iterator<string>(),
         [](const string& i) {
            char* it;
            double num = strtod(i.c_str(), &it);
            if (distance(i.c_str(), const_cast<const char*>(it)) == i.size()) cout << num << endl; });
```

However it is possible to accomplish this without the weight of an `istringstream` or a regex, by simply using [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok):

```
char buffer[] = " li 12.12 si 43,23 45 31 uf 889 uf31 3.12345";

for (auto i = strtok(buffer, " \f\n\r\t\v"); i != nullptr; i = strtok(nullptr, " \f\n\r\t\v")) {
    char* it;
    double num = strtod(i, &it);

    if (*it == '\0') cout << num << endl;
}
```

Note that for my delimiter argument I'm simply using the default [`isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) values.

Comment: No need escaping if raw string literal is used. `31` is not matched, BTW.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Wrong, notice those are non-capturing parenthesis.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the simplified use of second parameter of `strtod`. Took me a while to understand the documentation.

Comment: @user2079303 It seems we're the only ones on board with the `strtod` :( Ah well, if you're looking for a better explanation of how to use it you might want to check out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32991193/2642059

Answer (score 1):

Regexes are usually unreadable and hard to prove correct. Regexes matching only valid rational numbers need to be intricate and are easy to mess up. Therefore, I propose an alternative approach. Instead of regexes, tokenize your string with c++ and use `std::strtod` to test if input is a valid number. Here is example code:

```
std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& str) {
    std::istringstream iss(str);
    return {
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>{iss},
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>{}
    };
}

bool isValidNumber(const std::string& str) {
    char* end;
    std::strtod(str.data(), &end);
    return *end == '\0';
}

// ...
auto tokens = split(" li 12.12 si 43,23 45 31 uf 889 uf31 3.12345");
std::vector<std::string> matches;
std::copy_if(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), std::back_inserter(matches), isValidNumber);
```

Comment: You beat me to the use of `strtod` +1

Comment: yes, it's a possible way. But i have the solution of the problem.
I would like to reduce my code via regex, because if you use regex then you have a powerful tool by hands!! :) But, such as you are mentioned before, "Regexes are usually unreadable and hard to prove correct." :)

Comment: @user3641602 His solution is I believe a simpler one than the regex solution in the first place. I've streamlined his code in one of the options I provide in my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33521413/2642059

Answer (score 0):

Use negative lookahead and lookbehind to assert that there are no funny characters on either side of the number:

```
(?<![^\\s])(\\+|-)?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]*)?(?![^\\s])
```

Unfortunately you're going to need [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) for the task as the builtin one doesn't support these constructs.

You're probably better off splitting the input into *words* and then using a simple regex on each word.

Comment: C++ doesn't support look aheads or look behinds

Comment: ATM I don't really see another way of doing it.

Comment: Just a note: `[^\\s]` is looking for characters that are not `'\\'` or `'s'`. What you actually meant was `\S`

Comment: @JonathanMee: I escaped *all* the backlashes, assuming it's in a string. I probably should have used quotes.

Comment: @JonathanMee http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ECMAScript/ c++ support lookahead

Comment: I refuse and have always refused to use Boost. I prefer to use standard, for compatibility in team.

Comment: @user3641602: That's your own personal preference and choice, but I don't think it's something that should be advertised in comments.

Comment: @user3641602 You don't need Boost, [I was wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520934/regex-with-only-numbers-in-a-string-c/33521190?noredirect=1#comment54824766_33521564), this solution works without it. However the look ahead and behinds are expensive. Prefer a solution that doesn't use them: https://ideone.com/JSuULo or better yet a solution that uses `strtod`.

Answer (score 0):

Two attempts:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <sstream>


int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    string buffer(" li 12.12 si 43,23 45 31 uf 889 uf31 3.12345 .5");

    regex num_regex("(^|\\s)([\\+-]?([0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*|\\.?[0-9]+))(\\s|$)");
    smatch num_match;
    while (regex_search(buffer, num_match, num_regex))
    {
        if (num_match.size() >= 4) //3 groups = 4 matches
        {
            //We only need the second group
            auto token = num_match[2].str();
            cout << token << endl;
        }

        buffer = num_match.suffix().str();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <sstream>


int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    string buffer(" li 12.12 si 43,23 45 31 uf 889 uf31 3.12345 .5");

    istringstream iss(buffer);
    vector<string> tokens{ istream_iterator<string>{iss}, istream_iterator<string>{} };

    regex num_regex("^[\\+-]?([0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*|\\.?[0-9]+)$");
    for(auto token : tokens)
    {
        if (regex_search(token, num_regex))
        {
            //Valid entry
            cout << token << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: first is correct, but ignore 31 and .5
second ignore always

Comment: 31 is not ignored - I just tested both variants. You're right about `.5` - I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

You could play with a [trick](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick) to consume stuff you don't want. Something like this.

```
(?:\d+,|[a-z]+)\d+|(\d+[.\d]*)
```

Modfiy to everything that should be excluded in pipes pre capture and grab captures of first group.

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rY2iQ7/2). No idea if `(:` non capture group is ok for c++. Remove, if not.

Comment: Impressive way to think about it, but this will capture: "123abc" and "12#3" do you have a way to work around that?

Comment: @JonathanMee This approach only makes sense, if cases that could occur are known. For your samples have to [add those cases like this](https://regex101.com/r/tU2wH4/1).