# Read cin till EOF

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, eof

I was working on an example for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36646225/2642059) and I noticed that http://ideone.com will let me read till `EOF` from `cin` but Visual Studio 2015 will not.

For example, given the program:

```
string i;

while(cin >> i) cout << i << endl;
```

I can give the input:

> Lorem Ipsum

And http://ideone.com will terminate: http://ideone.com/22uNOr

Visual Studio 2015 will continue waiting for input however until I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> *and* hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Is this a gcc/Visual Studio difference or just something http://ideone.com is doing?

Comment: It's an ideone thing. It pipes the input to your program, it doesn't enter it interactively. (How would the interactive console know that no more input will be coming?)

Comment: @molbdnilo That's what I suspected... I just wasn't sure if gcc would let me extract to the end of `cin`, and since I don't have gcc available locally I thought I'd ask. Could you put that down as an answer?

Comment: @JonathanMee It's the same at coliru BTW.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I suppose so but, at least with http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ I'm doing the pipe myself. There isn't an indication of how http://ideone.com takes in the string I put in the "Input" text-box.

Comment: @MartjinPieters Are they burninating the ideone tag? Cause if not it really does seem to have a place in this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On http://ideone.com you can provide input on the "input" tab. Anything inputted into this box will be fed to `cin` appended with an `eof` character.

For example if you do:

```
while (cin.get() != decltype(cin)::traits_type::eof());
```

On your local machine that will never come back till you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> But on http://ideone.com it will always return after parsing everything typed into the "input" tab.