# Checking string to int error without loops/conditionals

Tags: c++, error-handling, conditional-statements, strtol

I'm doing a problem on HR and cant figure out how to check for error without using conditional statements. How is this done in C++?

```
// if string is int output it, else output "Bad string"
// need to do this without any loops/conditionals
int main(){
    string S;
    char *end;
    long x;
    cin >> S;
    const char *cstr = S.c_str();
    x = strtol(cstr,&end,10);

    if (*end == '\0')
        cout << x;
    else
        cout << "Bad string";

    return 0;
}
```

Should I be using something besides strtol?

Comment: [`std::stol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) takes a `std::string` and throws an exception if the conversion couldn't take place. Also, your title says `int`, but your code uses `long`. It doesn't matter too much, but please correct one or other to be consistent.

Comment: Can i make the exception a custom message if i use stoi? I actually need an int I was just testing with long.

Comment: You catch the exception (there are 2, for 2 different cases) and print out whatever you want.

Comment: Hmm I've never seen that before. What function do you use to catch an exception?

Comment: Hm, exceptions might be a little beyond what you have learned so far then. There is a basic introduction [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/152-basic-exception-handling/), but it shows catching simple things like `int`s, you would need to `catch(std::invalid_argument const& e) { ... }`. A catch block has nothing to do with functions.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: The specifications say it will be marked wrong if there are any loops or conditional statements. I guess I need to use `stoi` and then figure out how catching exceptions work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) is indeed what you'll want to use.

Given an input in `string S` one possible way to handle it would be:

```
try {
    cout << stoi(S) << " is a number\n";
} catch(const invalid_argument& /*e*/) {
    cout << S << " is not a number\n";
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/HTT3Dr)

The violation here is that `stoi` is only required to cosume the leading numeric part of the `string` *not* ensure that the entire string is an `int`. So "t3st" will fail cause it's not led by a number, but "7est" will succeed returning a 7. There are [a handful of ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32997831/2642059) to ensure that the entire `string` is consumed, *but* they all require an `if`-check.

Comment: I think the while loop will mark it wrong,  but thank you the catch line example is helpful

Comment: It worked! The try and catch blocks were what I needed, thanks.

Comment: @Jake I'm not sure what you mean, "the `while` loop will mark it wrong." It seems to work as expected in the example link.

Comment: It works, but solutions that use loops or conditionals are automatically marked wrong for this problem on HackerRank. I got it working without the loop though, thanks.

Comment: @Jake Lol, the loop was extraneous to the problem anyway, I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be:

```
char const *m[2] = { "Bad string", S.c_str() };
cout << m[*end == '\0'];
```

Comment: However innocent looking, the `==` is a conditional. If that's not considered an conditional statement, then I'd say the use of a ternary should be considered.

Comment: @JonathanMee I assumed "conditional statement" meant a statement with the conditional operator, or an `if` / `while` / `for`