# converting from std::string to uint8

Tags: c++, stdstring

referring to the beautiful solutions provided here,
[Convert string to int with bool/fail in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243428/convert-string-to-int-with-bool-fail-in-c),

I would like to cast a std::string to a 8 bit number (unsigned or signed)
The problem is that because 8 bit number is represented as a char so it is parsed wrong
(trying to parse anything above 1 digits - like 10 - fails)

Any ideas?

Comment: C++11 has these: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul but you'll still need to convert (ie `static_cast<uint8_t>`) the result and check bounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use template specialization:

```
template <typename T>
void Convert(const std::string& source, T& target)
{
    target = boost::lexical_cast<T>(source);
}

template <>
void Convert(const std::string& source, int8_t& target)
{
    int value = boost::lexical_cast<int>(source);

    if(value < std::numeric_limits<int8_t>::min() || value > std::numeric_limits<int8_t>::max())
    {
        //handle error
    }
    else
    {
        target = (int8_t)value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse the number as `int` and then cast it to `uint8_t`. You may perform bound checks as well.

Comment: that was my thinking... the problem is it ruins the pretty templating, I'm trying to figure out if there is more elegant solution

Comment: and adding to the point at hand - I have template function that accepts a <typename T> - What's a good way to exclude int8?